# Loop throug datalayer array for purchased products

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager

I have a datalayer purchase object with two products (but user can buy more products):

**This is an array I have:**

```
[
  {
    name: "Product1",
    id: 5986,
    price: 980,
    brand: "brand1",
    category: "Cable & Adapter",
    quantity: 1,
    dimension51: "",
    dimension52: "In Stock",
    metric11: 980,
    variant: 5771
  },
  {
    name: "Prooduct2",
    id: 5987,
    price: 980,
    brand: "brand2",
    category: "Cable & Adapter",
    quantity: 1,
    dimension51: "",
    dimension52: "In Stock",
    metric11: 980,
    variant: 5770
  }
]
```

I want to create a JS function that would concatenate from each product ProductID and VariantID and it will return a list of **productid_variantid**.

I would like to via js the following:

**5986_5771, 5987_5770**

I have already this JS but it is returning **undefined** in Google Tag Manager.

```html
function f(){
    var p = {{dataLayer.ecommerce.purchase.products}};
    var result = [];

    for(var i=0;i<p.length;i++){
        result.push(p[i].id.concat('_',p[i].variant));
    }

    return result.join(',');
}
```

Comment: Please try this: ``const pid_vid_string = origArray.map(({ id, variant }) => `${id}_${variant}`).join(',');`` where `origArray` is the array (shown in question, with 2 products - but, it can have any number of products as long as `id` and `variant` props exist, those will be concatenated as expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `f` can be replaced with the following:

**ES6:**

```
function f(){
  var p = {{dataLayer.ecommerce.purchase.products}};
  return p.map(({id, variant}) => `${id}_${variant}`).join(',');
}
```

**ES5:**

```
function f(){
  var p = {{dataLayer.ecommerce.purchase.products}};
  const results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    const product = p[i];
    const resultString = p[i].id + '_' + p[i].variant;
    results.push(resultString);
  }
  return results.join(',');
}
```

(The `{{dataLayer.ecommerce.purchase.products}}` syntax in your example is not valid in JavaScript, however I trust that this line works for you)

Comment: Hello Ovidijus, that is just the name of the variable :-)  The way I access the purchase product object is this way : ecommerce.purchase.products. It is the way it works in GTM to dynamically populate variables. Many thanks, let me check that please, but thank you for prompt response!

Comment: Dear Ovidijus, I am using the js in google tag manager but it states the following error :  Error at line 4, character 16: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: arrow function. I think maybe google tag manager does not support this. many thanks! PS: I have checked and an arrow function was intorduced at ES6 and GTM most probably has older version which returns compile error

Comment: Hi Mayo. In the context of the question I did not know that you were restricted to ES5, so from the stack overflow point of view my answer is valid. However, I'll update my response to es5 :)

Comment: Dear Ovidijus, neither I knew I am very sorry, and yes the solution is absolutely valid and tested outside of GTM. Thank you a lot for that!

Comment: Dear Ovidiijus, thank you so much, as stated, both answers are absolutely perfect and correct, but indeed GTM cannot consume anything from ECAMscript2015..Pardon me to ask, do you know, how to conver this into older versions that could be consumed?

Comment: You can try Babel, however I am not sure if it or any other automated transpiler can actually convert code to a format before ES5... What you have is definitely a unique constraint and would probably be worth raising as another question to get appropriate feedback

Comment: I accepted the solution worked properly even tough syntax on GTM had issues to consume it, but the proposed solution is OK. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that by a single line of code by using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

**Try this :**

```js
const products = [
  {
    name: "Product1",
    id: 5986,
    price: 980,
    brand: "brand1",
    category: "Cable & Adapter",
    quantity: 1,
    dimension51: "",
    dimension52: "In Stock",
    metric11: 980,
    variant: 5771
  },
  {
    name: "Prooduct2",
    id: 5987,
    price: 980,
    brand: "brand2",
    category: "Cable & Adapter",
    quantity: 1,
    dimension51: "",
    dimension52: "In Stock",
    metric11: 980,
    variant: 5770
  }
];

const res = products.map((obj) => `${obj.id}_${obj.variant}`);

console.log(res.join(', '));
```

Updated as per the author comment (With normal `forEach` loop) **:**

```js
const products = [
  {
    name: "Product1",
    id: 5986,
    price: 980,
    brand: "brand1",
    category: "Cable & Adapter",
    quantity: 1,
    dimension51: "",
    dimension52: "In Stock",
    metric11: 980,
    variant: 5771
  },
  {
    name: "Prooduct2",
    id: 5987,
    price: 980,
    brand: "brand2",
    category: "Cable & Adapter",
    quantity: 1,
    dimension51: "",
    dimension52: "In Stock",
    metric11: 980,
    variant: 5770
  }
];

const res = [];

products.forEach(function(obj) {
  res.push(`${obj.id}_${obj.variant}`);
}); 

console.log(res.join(', '));
```

Comment: Thank you Rohit, please, do you thing it would be possilbe to do it without arrow function as this seems to return an compile error? Appreciate and many thanks!

Comment: @MayoRacek If you dont want to use arrow function. Then you can do like this `products.map(function(obj) { return `${obj.id}_${obj.variant}` })`

Comment: Thank you a lot but google tag manager seems to have an issue with this format - ECMASCRIPT_2015 - more and more errors returning. Pardon me to ask, but is there any other way to achieve the same with syntax that is not ES6? Thank you a lot for your help :-)

Comment: @MayoRacek Yes you can simply achieve that using `forEach` loop. I updated my answer as well. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: Hello Rohit, please would it be possible to elaborate on this on js scrpit version older then 2015? GTM is not able to accept this format and version. Thank you